# Trying to create pie charts from points in QGIS show up empty circles

Tags: qgis, point, chart

I'm using QGIS 1.8.

I have a csv file with a list of nature reserves and their coordinates, and there are 10 columns such as 'birdwatching', 'scenery', etc with either 'yes' or 'no' under each for every nature reserve.

What I need to do is display all this as best I can on one map, and since most of the reserves have more than one attraction I figured the best way to do that is with the pie chart function.

When I add in all the attribute fields ('birdwatching', 'scenery' etc) all that I get is empty circles.

I've been playing aroud with settings but can't figure out how to make it work.

Comment: can you add a screenshot which shows a sample of your CSV file to get an idea about your fields and attributes

Comment: I see two different questions here. One, which I answered below, is how to make your data work with pie charts. The second question is how best to display your data, which is a broader and more subjective question. If you want some help with the second question, try posting a new question with the 'cartography' tag.

Answer (score 1):

The pie chart function requires a numerical input.

Use the Field Calculator to add a numerical version of each field, replacing each 'yes' with 1 and each 'no' with 0.

[image]
[image]

Generate pie charts using the numerical fields instead of the text fields.

[image]

Comment: I just noticed that your question was about QGIS version 1.8, while I use 3.0. I don't have the older version to test it on, but I think this will still work.

Comment: I'll try this tonight and see if it works! Thank you!

Comment: Apparently 'this layer does not support adding new provider fields. You can only add virtual fields". Any idea why this might be?

Comment: My guess is because it's a csv file. You can save a copy as a different file type and work from the copy. Or use virtual fields, which should be fine for this purpose.